# Strip Status Label não exibe imagem no Image Margin (Context Menu Strip)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Estou tentando inserir uma imagem em um StripStatusLabel, mas por algum motivo ela não é exibida no canto esquerdo, igual a um StripMenuItem.

As inserções estão sendo feitas da mesma maneira:

```
Dim teste As New ToolStripStatusLabel("Teste")
Dim sair As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sair")

teste.Image = My.Resources.Teste
sair.Image = My.Resources.Sair

cmsMagic.Items.Insert(0, teste)
cmsMagic.Items.Insert(1, sair)
```

Como fica:

[image: Como fica:]

Answer (score 0):

A questão é justamente o tipo de objeto diferente. Somente objetos `ToolStripMenuItem` têm acesso à tarja diferenciada do menu para colocarem suas imagens. Se você deseja este comportamento, deve usar este tipo para exibir o String "Teste", em vez de `ToolStripStatusLabel`